# O365 Group calendar events' attachment graph api returns access denied

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use this Graph API: /groups/{group_id}/events/{event_id}/attachments but keep getting 'ErrorAccessDenied' error. The documentation here: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/event_list_attachments mentions the read calendar scope and my app in azure ad has the right permissions. If I use the API me/events/{event_id}/attachments works.

Has anyone come across the similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need Groups.Read.All scope is this if for a group calendar.